# Get Flag values based on conditions in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server.
 Please tell me how to Flag values using time calculation in SQL Server based on conditions.
if out and in time difference is more than 5 hours then flag is 1 else 0

```
Table : employee
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employee](
    [Emp Id] [float] NULL,
    [Area Of Access] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [floor] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (101, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-03-03T03:36:58.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (101, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-03-03T03:38:55.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (101, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-03-05T18:54:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (101, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-03-05T18:54:13.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (101, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-03-05T18:54:32.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (101, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-03-05T18:55:01.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (101, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-03-05T19:58:41.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (100, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-02-06T16:03:08.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (100, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-06T22:01:40.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (100, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-02-06T22:42:15.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (100, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T00:33:19.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (100, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-02-07T10:13:11.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[employee] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (100, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T15:13:10.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
```

based on above table I want output like below :

```
EmpId   |Area Of Access |Time                           |floor                  |Flag
100 |IN         |2018-02-06 16:03:08.000    |Production Floor   |0
100 |OUT            |2018-02-06 22:01:40.000    |Production Floor   |0
100 |IN         |2018-02-06 22:42:15.000    |Production Floor   |0
100 |OUT            |2018-02-07 00:33:19.000    |Production Floor   |0
100 |IN         |2018-02-07 10:13:11.000    |Production Floor   |1
100 |OUT            |2018-02-07 15:13:10.000    |Production Floor   |0
101 |IN          |2018-03-03 03:36:58.000   |Common Area            |0
101 |OUT             |2018-03-03 03:38:55.000   |Common Area            |0
101 |OUT             |2018-03-05 18:54:00.000   |Common Area            |1
101 |IN          |2018-03-05 18:54:13.000   |Common Area            |0
101 |IN          |2018-03-05 18:54:32.000   |Common Area            |0
101 |IN          |2018-03-05 18:55:01.000   |Production Floor   |0
101 |OUT             |2018-03-05 19:58:41.000   |Production Floor   |0
```

I tried like below :

```
select el.*,  
case when (datediff(hh, lag(Time) over (partition by [Emp Id] order by Time), Time)) > 5
and el.[Area Of Access]='in' then 1  
when (datediff(hh, lag(Time) over (partition by [Emp Id]  order by Time), Time)) > 5
then 1   else 0 end  Flag from employee el
```

above query is not given expected result . Please tell me how to wirte query to achieve this task in SQL Server

Comment: Sry i cant understand your need. but one suggestion::: you've `0` or `1` flag. So go with if statement...--`iif(expr-1 operand expr-2, trueStatement, falseStatement)`  instead of `case when..`

Answer (score 0):

you can use lag function in case like that:

```
SELECT el.*,  
    CASE WHEN ((DATEDIFF(hh, LAG(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY [Emp Id] ORDER BY Time), Time)) > 5 
            AND LAG([Area Of Access]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Emp Id] ORDER BY Time) = 'out')
        THEN 1  
        ELSE 0 
    END  Flag 
FROM employee el
```